# In AysnckTask doInBackground Not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing this through AsyncTask but doInBackground is not working. Please tell me the error in this code, I am new in android programming. Is there any other way to do it? Please tell me the right way to do it.

Main Activity

```java
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        ListView listv;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> data;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            data = new ArrayList<String>();
            listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            context = this;

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
            listv.setAdapter(adapter);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             new AsyncCity().execute();


        }

        protected class AsyncCity extends AsyncTask<Void,JSONObject,ArrayList<cityTable>>
        {
            ArrayList<cityTable> cityTable=null;
            @Override
            protected ArrayList<cityTable> doInBackground(Void... params) {


                RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetCity();

                    JsonParse parser = new JsonParse();

                     cityTable= parser.parseCity(jsonObj);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block


                }
                return cityTable;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<cityTable> cityTables) {

                for (int i = 0; i < cityTables.size(); i++) {
                    data.add(cityTables.get(i).getCt_id() + " " + cityTables.get(i).getCt_name());
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(context,"Loading Completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    ---------------------------------------------
    //Json Parse
    ----------------------------------------

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by Abdurrehman Malik on 8/1/2015.
     */
    public class JsonParse {
        public JsonParse()
        {
            super();
        }

        ArrayList<cityTable>parseCity(JSONObject jsonObject)
        {
            ArrayList<cityTable> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Value");
                JSONObject jobj=null;
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    jobj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrayList.add(new cityTable(jobj.getInt("ct_id"), jobj.getString("ct_name")));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return arrayList;
        }
    }
    ------------------------
    //RestAPI
    ------------------------

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class RestAPI {
        private final String urlString = "http://pracwebservice.somee.com/Handler3.ashx";

        private static String convertStreamToUTF8String(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
            String result = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
                char[] buffer = new char[4096];
                int readedChars = 0;
                while (readedChars != -1) {
                    readedChars = reader.read(buffer);
                    if (readedChars > 0)
                       sb.append(buffer, 0, readedChars);
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }


        private String load(String contents) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            w.write(contents);
            w.flush();
            InputStream istream = conn.getInputStream();
            String result = convertStreamToUTF8String(istream);
            return result;
        }


        private Object mapObject(Object o) {
            Object finalValue = null;
            if (o.getClass() == String.class) {
                finalValue = o;
            }
            else if (Number.class.isInstance(o)) {
                finalValue = String.valueOf(o);
            } else if (Date.class.isInstance(o)) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Locale("en", "USA"));
                finalValue = sdf.format((Date)o);
            }
            else if (Collection.class.isInstance(o)) {
                Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>) o;
                JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
                for (Object item : col) {
                    jarray.put(mapObject(item));
                }
                finalValue = jarray;
            } else {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                Method[] methods = o.getClass().getMethods();
                for (Method method : methods) {
                    if (method.getDeclaringClass() == o.getClass()
                            && method.getModifiers() == Modifier.PUBLIC
                            && method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                        String key = method.getName().substring(3);
                        try {
                            Object obj = method.invoke(o, null);
                            Object value = mapObject(obj);
                            map.put(key, value);
                            finalValue = new JSONObject(map);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return finalValue;
        }

        public JSONObject GetCity() throws Exception {
            JSONObject result = null;
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
            o.put("interface","RestAPI");
            o.put("method", "GetCity");
            o.put("parameters", p);
            String s = o.toString();
            String r = load(s);
            result = new JSONObject(r);
            return result;
        }

    }

    ----------------------
    //cityTable
    ----------------------

    /**
     * Created by Abdurrehman Malik on 8/1/2015.
     */
    public class cityTable {

        int ct_id;
        String ct_name;

        public cityTable(int ct_id, String ct_name)
        {
            super();
            this.ct_id=ct_id;
            this.ct_name=ct_name;
        }
        public cityTable()
        {
            super();
            this.ct_id=0;
            this.ct_name=null;
        }
    public int getCt_id()
    {
        return ct_id;
    }
        public String getCt_name()
        {
            return ct_name;
        }
        public void setCt_id(int ct_id)
        {
            this.ct_id=ct_id;

        }
        public  void setCt_name(String ct_name)
        {
            this.ct_name=ct_name;
        }

    }
```

---

### //LOGCAT

```
Reconstruct Branch:
```

08-01 18:35:37.166  11908-11908/com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-01 18:35:37.296  11908-11908/com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-01 18:35:37.296  11908-11908/com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41751d58)
08-01 18:35:37.296  11908-11908/com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3, PID: 11908
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3.MainActivity$AsyncCity.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:67)
            at com.example.abdurrehmanmalik.webprac3.MainActivity$AsyncCity.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: App stopped when I run it  @PratikButani

Comment: Post your logcat, why app stopping?

Comment: @PratikButani Plz Check logcat.

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda mess...

All I can tell you that your crash is NullPointerException in your `onPostExecute()`. You didn't check null when you're trying to get values from your `cityTables`. Probably because you didn't parse it right.

You can find the reason if you log your JSON response and your `cityTables`.